# Кулер должен вдувать или выдувать воздух из компьютера?

Tags: железо

Подскажите, кулер на корпусе компьютера должен вдувать компьютер воздух или выдувать воздух из компьютера?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что проблемы с железом не являются допустимой темой Stackoverflow на русском языке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смотря где вентилятор находится.... на боковой стенке корпуса, над процессором, около HDD, на днище корпуса, на передней панели корпуса - как правило внутрь корпуса.на БП, под БП на задней стенке, рядом с видеокартой, на верхней стенке (крышке) корпуса - из корпуса наружу. Вообще стоит исходить из того, что теплый воздух поднимается вверх, и он должен удаляться из корпуса. А прохладный воздух должен нагнетаться в корпус снизу или напрямую к охлаждаемым элементам. Исключение составляет обдув радиаторов закрепленных на корпусе, там воздушный поток только из корпуса и снизу-вверх. При использовании систем пассивного охлаждения, все дополнительные потоки должны быть сонаправлены расчетным и не пересекаться с ними.

Answer (score 0):

На корпусе (напротив процессора) - чаще всего внутрь, на БП - 99% наружу.